# passing `onSubmit` as a prop in React.createElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
data = React.createElement(f, {onsubmit: a}, div.fields.map((d, i) => {
  let thisInput
  if (d.placeholder) {thisInput = React.createElement(d.format, {placeholder: d.placeholder, className: "captureEmail"})}
  if (d.value) {thisInput = React.createElement(d.format, {className: "btn"}, d.value)}
  return thisInput
}))
```

Particularly, I'm looking at `{onsubmit: a}` in the first line. I can pass `className` if I'd like but the `onsubmit` or `onclick` won't end up in the HTML. Is that a limitation in React?

Comment: Did you try with `onSubmit` (capital S)? React uses a slightly different notation

Comment: I did. still didn't like it :(

Comment: https://repl.it/@sheelpriy/CRA#src/index.js


something like yours and it is working.  when you press enter in the input button form gets submitted.  the only thing changed is `onSubmit` with S capital.

Comment: Awww... yours works in my code. it must be the variable `a` I'm passing. Will post when I figure it out - thanks!

Comment: @cjohndesign in React, buttons in forms are `submit` buttons by default. To prevent that, give the button the prop `type: "button"`

Answer (score 0):

In React, event names are camel cased. The compiler will covert it back to all lower case when constructing the compiled vanilla JS. To make it work, pass it the onsubmit event handler as onSubmit and the onclick event handler as onClick.

```
data = React.createElement(f, {onSubmit: a}, div.fields.map((d, i) => {
  let thisInput
  if (d.placeholder) {thisInput = React.createElement(d.format, {placeholder: d.placeholder, className: "captureEmail"})}
  if (d.value) {thisInput = React.createElement(d.format, {className: "btn", value: d.value})}
  return thisInput
}))
```

Comment: I just tried that again. It still doesn't like it - the HTML is simply <form>

Comment: @cjohndesign the problem now is how you're creating your input element. To set it's value, you have to set it has an html property, not as one of it's children:  `if (d.value) {thisInput = React.createElement('input', {className: "btn", value: d.value})}
` Input element's can't have children.